# How Can I avoid implicit move constructor inside a lambda function

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, emplace

I am using "emplace" method to avoid memory copy.
But, when I am using the "emplace" inside a Lambda function. It always call implicit move constructor.
How I can avoid memory copy inside a Lambda function?
This sample program should not print “I am being moved.”

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    int a;

    A(int t) : a(t)
    {
        std::cout << "I am being constructed.\n";
    }
    A(A&& other) : a(std::move(other.a))
    {
        std::cout << "I am being moved.\n";
    }
};

std::vector<A> g_a;

int main()
{
    std::cout << "emplace_back:\n";
    g_a.emplace_back(1);

    std::cout << "emplace_back in lambda:\n";
    auto f1 = [](int x) { g_a.emplace_back(x);  };  
    f1(2);

    std::cout << "\nContents: ";
    for (A const& t : g_a) 
        std::cout << t.a << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

It's not about the lambda function but rather about the vector that reallocates its memory. You can ammend this with `std::vector::reserve`.

```
int main() {
    g_a.reserve(10);
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    std::cout << "emplace_back:\n";
    g_a.emplace_back(1);

    std::cout << "emplace_back in lambda:\n";
    auto f1 = [](int x) { g_a.emplace_back(x);  };  
    f1(2);

    std::cout << "\nContents: ";
    for (A const& t : g_a) 
        std::cout << t.a << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/ImI8qrfgSqxRm7o3)